# where is ~\.vim folder in mac os? and how to install themes in gvim?

Tags: macos, vim, ide

I downloaded color sample pack from http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=625

it says i should unzip and place it into ~/.vim but where is this folder? I tried unzip it to my usr/share/.vim folder but it is not working, I don't see themes added to gvim Edit>color scheme menu, and i tried "colorscheme sometheme", "color sometheme" in my gvimrc. Both not working for new themes

Isn't the ~/.vim should be the .vim folder in use/share? or I should create a new folder under home?

Note:there is a folder vim73 in my .vim, I guess this doesn't affect anything

thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you try to create your own ~/.vim directory? This should work.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

First of all, open `vim`, and get help from `:help colorscheme`

```
:colo[rscheme] {name}   Load color scheme {name}.  This searches 'runtimepath'
                        for the file "colors/{name}.vim.  The first one that
                        is found is loaded.
```

After reading the manual above.
Take the following steps maybe help you:

- find runtimepath

  ```
  :set runtimepath?
  ```

  It will print out run-time paths:
  `runtimepath=~/.vim,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim71,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,~/.vim/after`
- create directory called `colors` under one of them if not exist(for example: `~/.vim`)

  ```
  $ ls ~/.vim
  ls: cannot access /root/.vim: No such file or directory <== we need create it!!!
  $ mkdir -p ~/.vim/colors
  ```
- copy your `color.vim` to your `colors` directory

  ```
  $ cp /path/to/your/color.vim  ~/.vim/colors
  ```
- restart `vim` to use new colorscheme

  ```
  :colorscheme color
  ```
- (optional) put command above to `~/.vimrc` file to make it permanent

Comment: Every time I open my vim it still use the default color scheme, it's not permanently.

Comment: @huangli You need to create a `vimrc` file, and put the command into `vimrc`.

Comment: Make sure to also put `:syntax enable` if you haven't already.

Answer (score 19):

In UNIX parlance, `~` represents your home folder which is `/Users/<username>` in Mac OS X.

You are supposed to put all your custom scripts/colorschemes/whatever in a `.vim` folder situated in your home folder. In Terminal.app, type each line (without the `$`) then hit Enter:

```
$ cd
```

to be sure you are in your home folder

```
$ mkdir .vim
```

here you'll have an error message if `~/.vim` already exists; if you don't receive a message it means that the folder is created

```
$ cd .vim
```

to move into it

```
$ open .
```

to open a Finder window here. At this point you should follow specific indications.

Comment: I think a lot of people don't know that you have to create your own .vim folder.